# Where to put html codes on wordpress php files

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I need help from wordpress experts on editing or creating themes. I have been trying to imitate the lol.garena.ph and so far what I've done was the nav button,here are the codes:

```
<style type="text/css">

body{

background-color:#000

}


Hh.hoverHome {
position: relative;
top: -3px; 
padding-bottom: 7px;
background:url(homeHover.png); /* this will raise the element */

}


Hn.hoverNews {
position: relative;
top: -3px; 
padding-bottom: 7px;
background:url(newsHover.png);

}


Hg.hoverGuides {
position: relative;
top: -3px; 
padding-bottom: 7px;
background:url(guidesHover.png);

}
Hh {
list-style: none;
height: 22px;
width: 79px;

float: left;
display: block;
padding: 5px 10px;
margin-right: 10px;
background:url(home.png);

}

Hn {
 list-style: none;
height: 22px;
width: 79px;

float: left;
display: block;
padding: 5px 10px;
margin-right: 10px;
background:url(news.png);

}

Hg {
 list-style: none;
height: 22px;
width: 79px;

float: left;
display: block;
padding: 5px 10px;
margin-right: 10px;
background:url(guides.png);

}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<div class="container">

</div>

<Hh onmouseover="this.className='hoverHome';" onmouseout="this.className='';">  </Hh>
<Hn onmouseover="this.className='hoverNews';" onmouseout="this.className='';"></Hn>
<Hg onmouseover="this.className='hoverGuides';" onmouseout="this.className='';"></Hg>

</body>
</html>
```

The problem I'm having is I don't know where to put this on wordpress theme because all I see are php files. I tried to insert the css part on the style.css on twentyeleven theme and the rest of the  parts on the content.php but it still does not work. I'm still new to Wordpress so please help me out, thank you.3

Comment: you want to upload a theme on wordpress! right?

Comment: How about editing the current theme's navigation's CSS

Comment: no sir, I'm just barely trying to put my codes and see if it works on wordpress but I think I'll get to your point of uploading my html files to wordpress, those php files are really hard to understand for a newbie like me.

Comment: Set up a copy of Wordpress locally, by installing a web sever - like `WAMP` for example (If you're on Windows). Then you can edit the default Twenty Twelve theme. You'll only need to change the `.css` file. Have a look at the markup that Wordpress generates, so you can apply your CSS according to the markup generated.

Comment: I tried creating a new css just to test it out <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sampleCSS.css" /> but still does not work.

Comment: @Nick yes I've setup my wordpress website and proceeded to editing and possibly creating a theme by copying lol.garena.ph.

Comment: @rsarellano You have `Hn` and `Hn` in your CSS, this is not valid. Look at the menu markup the theme produces in your browser, and style it according to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not really sure of your question with regards to what you are trying to achieve, however if you want to work with an existing theme to base your new theme on, I would advise using WordPress Child Themes.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

With child themes you can create a new child style.css file to make all your changes for CSS. The benefit of using a child theme is that you can quickly make changes to the existing CSS and PHP files without changing any of the core files.

This is very beneficial in the long run as it means that you are able to update your WordPress themes without any of your existing CSS and PHP changes being overwritten.

I hope this helps you with your quest to create a WordPress theme. I would advise looking at the WordPress tutorials on Treehouse (teamtreehouse.com) if you have an account or you can go to YouTube to find other great tutorials that might help.

Comment: I'll second the team treehouse recommendation. Their tutorials are awesome!